# When does the "choose a color" part of a spell happen?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example [Sejiri Steppe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sejiri%20Steppe). I always did it as follows:
Opponent plays Sejiri Steppe, chooses a creature and a color, then I get to respond.

But today while playing, after my opponent played Sejiri Steppe, he said he was only supposed to say the color if the ability resolved.
Do I get to know what color the protection from will be before answering the ability, or I have to decide if I answer it before he decides the color?

Answer (score 9):

The ability reads as follows:

> When Sejiri Steppe enters the battlefield, target creature you control gains protection from the color of your choice until end of turn.

The color is chosen when the ability resolves. At that point, there's no chance for anyone to respond. Here's what happens in more detail:

- The ability triggers. Its controller chooses a target for the ability.
- Both players have a chance to cast spells or activate abilities.
- The ability resolves. A color is chosen, and the target gets protection from the chosen color.

Here's a ruling on [Feat of Resistance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Feat%20of%20Resistance), a card that has similar wording:

> 9/20/2014 You choose the color as Feat of Resistance resolves.

Answer (score 5):

Your opponent chooses which color as the ability resolves. In general, if you have choices to make for a spell or ability, those are made as it resolves. The main choices you have to make when the ability first goes on the stack are modes (things that say "choose one:" or the like with a list after) and targets. Things like "a color of your choice" let you delay your choice.